# How to draw forms using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How to draw something like this using TikZ please?

[image]

So I'm trying here to draw one cercle related to two lines which are related to one rectangle, with the preservation of the white colors (noncontinuous lines).
Any brilliant proposition, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What object is it?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer, cercle, two lines, rectangle.

Comment: One of the first things to learn in TikZ is to draw lines and rectangles. Reading the manual is the best way to learn that. If you do not want to learn, but just want the result, this is not the right place to ask.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen, I just want to see better creations.

Comment: A minor question: what does the [tag:beamer] have to do with your question?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, to put the question in its context. It's maybe their is some specific packages or other better suggestions related to it.

Comment: @dgs: sorry, which context? Drawing a, ehm.. "abstract" figure like the one you linked is totally independent of the type of document class (i.e. beamer or standard article).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, would you please help to put the question in its context by editing its tags?

Comment: @dgs: I think after being member of the site for more than 3 months, you should know how to select the proper tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dangerous object with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

% b a t p2c ---> x y
% where b (semi-minor), a (semi-major), t (theta)
\pstVerb{/p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors](10,10)
\pnode[2,6](!1.5 2 30 p2c){P0}
\pnode[2,6](!1.5 2 -30 p2c){P1}
\pnode(2,6){P2}
\pscustom[origin={P2},fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
{
    \psellipticarc(P2)(2,1.5){(P0)}{(P1)}
    \translate(!N-P2.x neg N-P2.y neg)
    \psline(7,0|P1)(7,2)(9.5,2)(9.5,8)(7,8)(7,0|P0)
    \closepath
}
\rput(2,6){Don't touch!}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- when `psellipticarc` used inside `pscustom`, `origin` must be invoked via `pscustom` to avoid strange behavior.
- `\translate(P2)` does not produce the expected result.